# vanishing tensor product, geometric meaning

Tags: tensor-products

We can derive the following property directly. 
" $\mathbb{Z}_m \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}_n = O$. where $m,n$ are relatively prime.
But, this is just a simple computation. I want to know the geometric meaning(or visualization) of this result (for example, n,m=1,2).

Comment: Look up "support." The geometric meaning is that you have two $\mathbb{Z}$-modules with disjoint support.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan/ Could you explain the detail?